# linq case query behaviour with anonymous types

Tags: c#, sql, linq, case, anonymous-types

I have the following linq query

```
var result = from myTypes in context.MyTypes
where
  ((myTypes .Prop1== "Test" ? 1 : 0) + 
  (myTypes .Prop2 == "Tester2" ? 1 : 0) + 
  (myTypes .Prop3 == "624642624000000000" ? 1 : 0) + 
  (myTypes .Prop4 == "TS166TH" ? 1 : 0) + 
  (myTypes .Prop5 == "1 Test Lane" ? 1 : 0)) >= 4
  select new {
  myTypes .Prop1,
  myTypes .Prop2,
  myTypes .Prop3,
  myTypes .Prop4,
  myTypes .Prop5,
  myTypes .OtherProp,
  myTypes .OtherTypeId
};

result.ToList();
```

This results in the following expected SQL which is what I want to achieve

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Prop1] AS [Prop1], 
[Extent1].[Prop2] AS [Prop2], 
[Extent1].[Prop3] AS [Prop3], 
[Extent1].[Prop4] AS [Prop4], 
[Extent1].[Prop5] AS [Prop5], 
[Extent1].[OtherProp] AS [OtherProp], 
[Extent1].[OtherTypeId] AS [OtherTypeId],

FROM [dbo].[MyType] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ((CASE WHEN ('Test' = [Extent1].[Prop1]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN ('Tester2' = [Extent1].[Prop2]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN ('624642624000000000' = [Extent1].[Prop3]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN ('TS166TH' = [Extent1].[Prop4]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN ('1 Test Lane' = [Extent1].[Prop5]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 4
```

However I want to return MyType not an anonymous type so I wrote the following

```
var result = from myTypes in context.MyTypes
where
  ((myTypes .Prop1== "Test" ? 1 : 0) + 
  (myTypes .Prop2 == "Tester2" ? 1 : 0) + 
  (myTypes .Prop3 == "624642624000000000" ? 1 : 0) + 
  (myTypes .Prop4 == "TS166TH" ? 1 : 0) + 
  (myTypes .Prop5 == "1 Test Lane" ? 1 : 0)) >= 4
  select myTypes; 

result.ToList();
```

Which I would expect to generate the same query but return my type.  Instead I find it performs a massive recursive query (essentially querying every record in the table) As below.

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Prop1] AS [Prop1], 
[Extent1].[Prop2] AS [Prop2], 
[Extent1].[Prop3] AS [Prop3], 
[Extent1].[Prop4] AS [Prop4], 
[Extent1].[Prop5] AS [Prop5],
[Extent1].[OtherProp] AS [OtherProp],
[Extent1].[OtherTypeId] AS [OtherTypeId],
FROM [dbo].[MyType] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ((CASE WHEN ('Test' = [Extent1].[Prop1]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN ('Tester2' = [Extent1].[Prop2]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN ('624642624000000000' = [Extent1].[Prop3]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN ('TS166TH' = [Extent1].[Prop4]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN ('1 Test Lane' = [Extent1].[Prop5]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 4
GO

SELECT 
[Extent1].[OtherTypeId] AS [OtherTypeId], 
[Extent1].[OtherTypeProp] AS [OtherTypeProp], 
FROM [dbo].[OtherTypes] AS [Extent1]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE EntityKeyValue1 BigInt = 1
-- EndRegion
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Prop1] AS [Prop1], 
[Extent1].[Prop3] AS [Prop2], 
[Extent1].[Prop3] AS [Prop3], 
[Extent1].[Prop4] AS [Prop4], 
[Extent1].[Prop5] AS [Prop5], 
[Extent1].[OtherProp] AS [OtherProp], 

WHERE [Extent1].[OtherTypeId] = @EntityKeyValue1
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE EntityKeyValue1 BigInt = 2
-- EndRegion
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Prop1] AS [Prop1], 
[Extent1].[Prop3] AS [Prop2], 
[Extent1].[Prop3] AS [Prop3], 
[Extent1].[Prop4] AS [Prop4], 
[Extent1].[Prop5] AS [Prop5], 
[Extent1].[OtherProp] AS [OtherProp], 

WHERE [Extent1].[OtherTypeId] = @EntityKeyValue1
GO
```

It looks like It's getting all the fk types for EVERY record and ignoring the where clause?

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here and why are the  two generated query's different?

Comment: What SQL is produced by the latter example?

Comment: Can you post ``MyType`` code?

Comment: MyType is just an entity class with the 6 properties (seen in the example) within it.

Comment: Ive updated the question so you mean what happens if I do select new { myTypes }.  ill try

Comment: I get the same result.  It seems to be trying to Get the FK types for myType but for ALL records and ignoring the where clause.

Comment: _"However I want to return MyType not an anonymous type"_ -- Then simply write `new MyType { … }` instead of `new { … }`!

Comment: @stakx  And obvious point. I hadn't thought of just initialising the type and setting all props manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK That was embarrassing.

I was using LinqPad to test the query and was calling a `Dump()` on the `ToList()` result.  Dump() enumerates all the properties which caused a cyclic enumeration through all related records in the db.  Where as a Dump on the anonymous types  just list all the properties and no entity Navigation properties cause enumeration.

A note to all using LinqPad's Dump() method on Entity's in future.  Apologies to all for wasting time.  School boy error.